# Python - How to use append in combination with lambda expression to get an array of 0s and 1s

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a function that takes two arguments as input: the vocabulary which is an array of words, and the raw email text (original_email). The function should return an array of the same size as the vocabulary array, where the j-th element of this array indicates whether or not the j-th vocabulary word is present in the preprocessed version of original_email.
I have tried with the code below:

```
def email_to_vector(vocabulary, original_email):
    email_words = processEmail(original_email).split(" ") # List of words in the preprocessed version of original_email
    set_email_words = set(email_words)
    s = []
    for word in vocabulary:
        s.append(lambda word: 1 if word in set_email_words else 0)
    return s
```

What I get as return of this function is a gibberish like this:

```
[<function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA52F70>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BE9B0D0>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BE9B430>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BF00280>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BF00DC0>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A0D0>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A1F0>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A160>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A670>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A550>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A5E0>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A4C0>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BA7A280>, <function email_to_vector.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002182BE8BE50>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a `lambda` here, the expression already does what you need:

```
for word in vocabulary:
    s.append(1 if word in set_email_words else 0)
```

You can also shorten this to:

```
return [1 if word in set_email_words else 0 for word in vocabulary]
```